# After Effects - Animation > Keyframe Assistant > Grayed Out

Tags: after-effects

I'm a novice in regards to After Effects, but what I'm trying to do seems like it should be simple...yet I'm struggling here.

Here's the issue:

I have an image that I'm starting off at 0% scale, and over 4 seconds I'm bringing it to 100% scale. This I've done successfully.

However! I'm trying to stop the image at about 50% scale for a second to give people a chance to look at it. After which, the scaling up would resume.

According to the tutorials online, I need to use the properties found under Animation > Keyframe Assistant...this every option here is grayed out for me.

Am I totally missing something here?

Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To access Keyframe Assistant, you need to select at least one key.
To view the existing keys in all layers - press "U" twice in a row with a short interval